Importing file issues with new Blender version 4.2 texture missing
I downloaded a file from Blender Swap. I noticed the file was created in Blender 2.7, When I append the file in Blender 4.2, this is what's showing up, the Green leaves are missing.
Also no texture is included with the object. But I can see it in the materials property, the folder which I downloaded is corrupted?
https://blendswap.com/blend/17143





Blender's materials have changed a lot over the different versions. As you can see in the Material Properties to the right in your first screenshot, there is a button saying Use Nodes. It is there because the material does not use any shader nodes. When you switch to the Shader Editor you can also see that there is nothing and the Use Nodes option is not checked:

This is because the old material is probably from the old internal render engine and not compatible with current Blender versions. What you have to do is create the material (to be more precise, create the shader nodetree, the current material can be used) yourself. Either click the button Use Nodes in the material properties or check the option in the Shader Editor.
Then you'll get a new nodetree with a basic material containing a Principled BSDF and a Material Output. Now you can add an Image Texture node, select one of the two fern image textures, plug the Image output into the Base Color and the Alpha output into the Alpha input of the Principled BSDF.
By default the Image Texture node uses UV mapping so this should work immediately, but of course you can use a Texture Coordinate node if you want to change something and also adjust everything else to your liking (the original material was only diffuse, no glossiness or anything).

